# how to delete preview file icon from upload file antd?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't want to use preview file icon.
How to delete preview file icon from file upload antd

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable/hide preview icon with `showUploadList` to the upload list

```
<Upload
        action="https://run.mocky.io/v3/435e224c-44fb-4773-9faf-380c5e6a2188"
        listType="picture-circle"
        fileList={fileList}
        onChange={handleChange}
        showUploadList={{
          showPreviewIcon:false
        }}
      >
        {fileList.length >= 8 ? null : uploadButton}
      </Upload>
```

[image]

https://ant.design/components/upload

[image]